# Corrosion on battery post

Tags: battery, car, corrosion

Would corrosion on battery post cause my car not to start?

I can charge the car and it still will not start but if i clean the post it will start every time.

Comment: How often does this happen?  you might want to consider replacing your clamps.

Answer (score 3):

This goes straight back to [Ohms Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) as the corrosion is effectively adding a resistor into the starter circuit this reducing the amount of current the starter motor can physically draw.  Starting the engine is the most intensive duty your cars electrical system has to perform.

A this smear of grease on the battery terminals following a good clean should prevent corrosion from re-occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen, so yes. The starter motor has a high current draw, corrosion will affect the starter more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Boil a kettle and pour boiling water over the terminals this clean the terminal perfectly then put vasoline on the terminals.

Comment: I'd advise extreme caution with this approach as there is a risk that water gets into the wiring harness of the car which could cause untold damage.  There is also a risk of injury.  I'd be included to stick to more traditional methods such as using a piece of abrasive cloth / emery paper to clean up the connectors.